# rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan not working

Tags: rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I  am using turtlebot 2 with astra pro sensor on ubuntu 14 with ros indigo.
when i run

$rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=camera/depth/image_raw

i get no response or any output window,  whereas i can easily get rgb, ir and depth images using rosrun commands.
can anybody help if there is needed some extra configuration in order to make it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342892/rosrun-depthimage_to_laserscan-not-working/) by [noor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26717/noor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`depthimage_to_laserscan` takes a depth image (sensor_msgs/Image), converts it to a Laserscan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) and publishes it. No "output window" is created.

By default the LaserScan is published on the `/scan` topic.
You can check it exists with `rostopic list | grep "/scan"`

To visualize it, the most common would be to add a `LaserScan` plugin in RViz and select the `/scan` topic.

---

If this doesn't answer your question, can you please edit it to provide more information:

- What you are trying to accomplish
- What "response or output window" you
  expected?
- "i can easily get rgb, ir
  and depth images using rosrun
  commands" -> What commands are you
  referring to ?
- Any useful
  additional information following the
  [Support
  Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26717/noor/) on 2020-01-30**:
is it necessary to run rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan command in order to publish laser scan data? or it is by default available when ros astra is running.
and how can i check the values of sensor_msgs/Image? is there any command to get this value? i want to check whether it is receiving data or not?

**Comment by [noor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26717/noor/) on 2020-01-30**:
i have run this command
$rostopic list | grep "/scan" and i got this message "/scan" and when i run command $rostopic echo /scan ,
i get following message
"header:
seq: 45722
stamp:
secs: 1580386854
nsecs: 953619949
frame_id: camera_depth_frame
angle_min: -0.51137316227
angle_max: 0.483443826437
angle_increment: 0.00155683408957
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0329999998212
range_min: 0.449999988079
range_max: 10.0
ranges: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ]
intensities: "
is it working, i don't know.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-01-30**:\

> is it working, i don't know.

Without any information about what your setup is, what tutorial you are following and what you are trying to accomplish it's hard to tell

Please edit your original question with more information as suggested in the answer above

**Comment by [noor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26717/noor/) on 2020-01-31**:
problem solved. Thanks for all your support.
I have plotted the data received from /scan topic on MATLAB. I am using it for obstacle avoidance and navigation. The main reason that i was not receiving the scan topic data for astra pro 3d sensor is that i was missing the command  $rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw for astra.